# Can’t get expoToken in Expo Notification, due to Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId;

Tags: expo, expo-notifications

Good afternoon, hope you guys have a good day, i'm already building some apps using expo bare workflow, and need to use Expo Notification, i'm following all the instruction, from [expo notification documentations](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/), and [fcm configurations](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/using-fcm/), to [setup firebase](https://docs.expo.io/guides/setup-native-firebase/#android-1), but, when i'm tryin to get expoToken, i got this **warning**, looks like this:

```
Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method getDevicePushTokenAsync on module ExpoPushTokenManager: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId;
```

and I've made sure that my package name is the same as the package I registered in firebase, can you guys help me? pleasee :slight_smile:

this is **addtional information**:

> Getting Expo Token

```
const getToken = async () => {
    console.log("TOKEN CHECK");
    const { status: existingStatus } =
      await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
      finalStatus = status;
    }
    if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
      alert("Failed to get push token for push notification!");
      return;
    }
    token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
    console.log(token);
  };
```

> App.js

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "displayName": "myapp",
  "expo": {
    "name": "myapp",
    "slug": "myapp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ]
  },
  "android": {
    "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
    "useNextNotificationsApi": true
  }
}
```

> Package.json

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "start": "react-native start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@dudigital/react-native-zoomable-view": "^1.0.16",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.5",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^6.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^12.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^12.0.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.16.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.3.15",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "expo": "~41.0.1",
    "expo-av": "~9.1.2",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~9.1.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~10.1.4",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.11.6",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.10.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "expo-updates": "~0.5.4",
    "expo-web-browser": "~9.1.0",
    "firebase": "^8.6.5",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "~0.63.4",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1263.0",
    "react-native-custom-qr-codes-expo": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-orientation-locker": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.1",
    "react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^5.1.1",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.0.0",
    "react-native-shimmer-placeholder": "^2.0.7",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.13.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

screenshot:
[someImages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXUjP.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do two things:

1. In bare workflow, the Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync() method needs to provide the experienceId attributes.

```js
const expoPushToken = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({ experienceId });

console.log({ expoPushToken });

return expoPushToken.data;
```

2. You have to modify your */android/app/build.gradle* to add **'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.2'**

   dependencies {
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.2'
   ...
   }